# android facebook authorization onActivityResult() always getting called with data as null and resultCode is 0 (zero/RESULT_CANCELED)

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to integrate facebook into an android application. I have added the code the facebook authorization (followed all the steps as per guidelines from here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/). 
Whenever the facebook authorization happens, onActivityResult will be called back but with data as null and resultCode as 0 (zero/RESULT_CANCELED).

Here's my code:

Main Activity class

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {        
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);        
    MCAndroidFBIntegration.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

MCAndroidFBIntegration.java

public class MCAndroidFBIntegration implements IFacebookIntegration {

```
private static final String APP_ID = APP_ID_NUMBER;
private static Facebook facebook;
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFBRunner;
public Preferences mPrefs;
private Context ctx;
private static MCAndroidFBIntegration mcAndroidFBIntegration;

public MCAndroidFBIntegration(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public void integrate() {
    // Integrate with Facebook
    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    mAsyncFBRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    loginToFacebook();      
}

private void loginToFacebook() {
    mPrefs = GamePreference.getPreferences();
    String accessToken = mPrefs.getString(Config.ACCESS_TOKEN, null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong(Config.ACCESS_EXPIRES, 0);

    if (accessToken != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(accessToken);
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize((Activity) ctx, new String[] { "publish_stream",
                "read_stream", "offline_access"}, new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // Function to handle cancel event
                System.out.println("Facebook:: event cancelled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // Function to handle complete event
                // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                System.out
                        .println("Facebook:: setting access token and expire time in preferences");
                User user = User.getUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    user.setAccessToken(facebook.getAccessToken());
                    user.setAccessExpires(facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    user.updatePrefs();
                    mPrefs.flush();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError error) {
                // Function to handle error
                System.out.println("Facebook:: Error - "
                        + error.getLocalizedMessage());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                // Function to handle Facebook errors
                System.out.println("Facebook:: fbError - code: "
                        + fberror.getErrorCode() + "  message: "
                        + fberror.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

        });
    }
}

public static void authorizeCallback(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        String error = data.getStringExtra("error");
        if (error != null) {
            String description = data.getStringExtra("error_description");
            System.out.println("Facebook:: error desc - " + description);
        } else {
            String token = data.getStringExtra("access_token");
            String expires = data.getStringExtra("expires_in");
            System.out.println("Facebook:: call back access token - "
                    + token);
            System.out.println("Facebook:: call back expires - " + expires);
        }
    }
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

Cam someone please tell me what is the mistake that I'm doing here.

Thanks,
Kamal

Comment: I get this in log always.**Activity is launching as a new task, so cancelling activity result**. What does this mean? I searched over the net for this and found that this has something to do with android:launchMode="singleInstance". But when I changed this, I got some other errors like Authentication failed because of invalid android app key. What do I do? I'm so confused and exhausted

Comment: Hi Kamal, did you manage to solve this problem? I am facing the same problem but very confused

Answer (score 1):

I kinda faced the same problem. and update below code to solve it.

```
public void loginAndPostToWall() {
  facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
        new LoginDialogListener());}
```